# Detecting and extracting names from a binary dataframe based on duplicate percentage

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
                   sample1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), sample2 = c(1L, 
                                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), sample3 = c(0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           -10L))
```

Species column values are duplicated here. 1/0 indicates presence and absence.

For each sample I want to count presence of  duplicate species at different percentage value.
For example, lets say my cut off % is 80.
Number of duplicates in a is 2.
80% of 2 is 1.6 ~ 2 (nearest whole number).
Similarly, Number of duplicates in b is 5.
80% of 5 is  4.
Number of duplicates in c is 3.
80% of 3 is 2.4 ~2.

In each duplicate, if the sample count (sum of 1's)  is more than or equal to 80% count , I will write the species in the sample.

Final output will be:

```
out_df<-structure(list(sample1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"c"), class = "factor"), sample2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"a"), class = "factor"), sample3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
threshold <- 0.8

df1 <- df %>%
  add_count(species) %>%
  mutate(n = round(n * threshold)) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(across(sample1:sample3, ~sum(.) >= first(n))) %>% 
  #In old dplyr you can use `summarise_at`
  #summarise_at(vars(sample1:sample3), ~sum(.) >= first(n))
  data.frame()

#  species sample1 sample2 sample3
#1       a   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#2       b   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
#3       c    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
```

To get same output as shown :

```
mat <- which(as.matrix(df1[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
df1[-1][!df1[-1]] <- NA
df1[-1][mat] <- as.character(df1$species[mat[, 1]])
df1[-1]

#   sample1 sample2 sample3
#1     <NA>       a      NA
#2     <NA>    <NA>      NA
#3       c     <NA>      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution,

```
m1 <- sapply(split(df, df$species), function(i)1 * (colSums(i[-1]) >= round(nrow(i)*0.8)))
p1 <- which(m1 == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
m1[p1] <- colnames(m1)[p1[,'col']]

as.data.frame(t(m1))

#  sample1 sample2 sample3
#a       0       a       0
#b       0       0       0
#c       c       0       0
```